# getting data from one django to a template from another django app

Tags: django, django-templates

Have Two Django Apps.
**Work** and **Blog**

The Blog App template folder has the **index.html**

Here is the **view.py** from **work**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import models
from work.models import Work
from blog import views

# Create your views here.

def work_(request):
    template_name = "blog/templates/index.html"
    work_list = Work.objects.all
    context={'work_list':work_list}
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

I want it to be shown in **index.html** which is in the blog app

```
<div class="work">
            <section id = "work-list">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class = "row">
                        {% for works in work_list %}
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="lol">
                                        <img class="img-rounded img-responsive" src = "{{works.image}}" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {%endfor%}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
```

**index.html** is in the blog app

This is the directory

```
blog
   template
      index.html
   models.py
   views.py

Work
   views.py
   models.py
```

[image] **Picture from Developer tools**

i tried to put in a print statement in the **views.py**
And it did not print in the console. 
Apparently something is wrong in the **url.py**

```
    urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^blogposts/$', views.BlogPosts.as_view(), name='blogposts'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^contact/$', contact_views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^privacy/$', privacy_views.privacy, name='privacy'),
    url(r'^feed/$', feed.LatestPosts(), name='feed'),
    url(r'^work/$', work_views.work_, name='work'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.detailview, name='entry_detail'),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls'))


]
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Apps are just logical groupings of models, views and templates, there is no barrier to using data defined in one app in another.

Comment: I am trying to get some data from work app to index.html...
Normally it should work fine, but for some reason nothing seems to work for me..

Comment: What does "nothing seems to work" mean? What do you see? What HTML is produced?

Comment: Nothing.. That is the issue

Comment: You have to check template dirs in the settings of your project or you can add one global templates folder which will store folders accoring to your app names and there you will have to store the templates.

Comment: Is that your actual code? `template_name = "blog/templates/index.html"` would give you a template does not exist error (unless you have a template at `blog/templates/blog/templates/index.html`). Also, you are missing parentheses in `work_list = Work.objects.all()`.

Comment: i have index.html in blog/templates folder..!!

Comment: As I said, is that your actual code? If index is in `blog/templates` then you would do `template_name = "index.html"`. Your code `template_name = "blog/templates/index.html"` would give an error saying the template does not exist.

Comment: By the way, if 'DEBUG = True' in the settings.py, you can see the origin of the problem

Comment: As an aside, your URL patterns clash -- requests for `/ckeditor/` will be handled by the `entry_detail` URL pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a few mistakes that I can detect. 
1. It should be `work_list = Work.objects.all()`, you are missing the `()` at the end.
2. Your template file should be placed in this manner: `/blog/templates/blog/index.html`
3. In the html file, while inserting the image `src` you have to write `{{ works.image.url }}` to actually show an image. Otherwise, you won't see anything. `<img src="{{ works.image.url }}"/>`

#### Edit

after you have put your urls.py:
You have to create different apps to handle different functions, each of them containing an `urls.py` file. You cannot direct urls to specific functions from the main `urls.py`. So, do this in the main urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

then create a file in the blog app (or any other app you need) named `urls.py` and in that:

```
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name='home'),
url(r'^blogposts/$', views.BlogPosts.as_view(), name='blogposts'),
]
```

Comment: @SanjeevSiva glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

u havent imported the models from the other blog app
so in the views, put something like 
from blog.models import Blog
then the templates folder path should be
blog\templates\blog for the blog app not template